# Changing Django/Aldryn boilerplate

Tags: django-cms, boilerplate, divio

I have created a project (and invested significant time & effort on it :-) ) .

When I try to add add-ons it complaints about some missing bits and pieces. Looking around, the root cause seems to be that I created this with the default barebones boilerplate, instead of the richer bootstrap3 boilerplate.

However, there is no option I can find to change the boilerplate. Is it possible to change the boilerplate it is built on? Is there a magic concoction...?

Answer (score 0):

An Aldryn employee helped me out in their chatroom with this problem -- if you're trying to make changes on your templates and whatnot locally, and they aren't being reflected on the site when you deploy the test server, you can get things re-synched by totally deleting your local files, opening the test server with the desktop client, and clicking on the "auto-sync this project" button. This takes what's on the test server, and rebuilds the local files on your computer with that. Then, your local changes (remember to save your changes first!) should be reflected when you deploy the test server (after clicking on the "Refresh Projects" button in the lower righthand corner of the desktop client).

If you have a ton of work that you'd rather not delete and rewrite, you can move your local files elsewhere on your hard drive, and then replace the files that are written from the test server with them.

Cheers to Angelo for helping me with that. It's kind of a quirky solution, and I'd have never figured it out on my own.

You can also add custom boilerplates [here](https://control.aldryn.com/account/my-boilerplates/) (I think that'll make you log in to your account to see it), but I haven't attempted a custom boilerplate, yet, so I can't vouch for how well one would jive with the rest of the Aldryn platform.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that, while the title is unlikely to grab the interest of somebody who's making their own boilerplates, the first two or three entries [in this series](http://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2016/02/16/build-a-website-without-knowing-python-django-part-two/) could be quite helpful in implementing your custom work into Aldryn's framework.